# Parsing long XML string in Objective C with NSXMLParser

Tags: ios, xml, uitableview

I have a long string of XML that I need to parse and get data from. I ideally want to take this data and apply it to variables, which I can then populate a UITableView with. I have searched and searched, and I really haven't been able to find any code that applies data to variables. Here is the code I have to get the XML:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

// This is our soap message. This sends the wsdl request to the server.
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"> <soapenv:Header/>\n <soapenv:Body>\n <getUserRegistrations>\n <usr>this info is sensitive</usr>\n </getUserRegistrations>\n </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>"];

// This tells the URL requester where to point.
NSURL *locationOfWebService = [NSURL URLWithString:@"this url is sensitive"];

// Log the input of the URL
NSLog(@"web url = %@",locationOfWebService);

// Send a URL request to the server
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:locationOfWebService];

// Log the length of the wsdl request
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[soapMessage length]];

// Header stuff - from w3schools
[theRequest addValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue:@"http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
//the below encoding is used to send data over the net
[theRequest setHTTPBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// Variables for the response
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *data_reply;
NSError *err;

// This is the reply from the server
data_reply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest    returningResponse:&response error:&err];

// Apply this data to a string and log it in the debugger
NSString *aStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data_reply encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"aStr:%@",aStr);

}
```

and here is the response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <getUserRegistrationsResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <getUserRegistrationsReturn xsi:type="ns1:QueryBean" xmlns:ns1="http://rpc.xml.coldfusion">
    <columnList soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[10]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
     <columnList xsi:type="xsd:string">REGID</columnList>
     <columnList xsi:type="xsd:string">WORKSHOP</columnList>
     <columnList xsi:type="xsd:string">EVENT</columnList>
     <columnList xsi:type="xsd:string">WSNAME</columnList>
     <columnList xsi:type="xsd:string">EVENTDATE</columnList>
     <columnList xsi:type="xsd:string">WSLOCATION</columnList>
     <columnList xsi:type="xsd:string">WSCITY</columnList>
     <columnList xsi:type="xsd:string">WSSTATE</columnList>
     <columnList xsi:type="xsd:string">HOSTCONSORTIUMABRV</columnList>
     <columnList xsi:type="xsd:string">CONSORTIUMABRV</columnList>
    </columnList>
    <data soapenc:arrayType="xsd:anyType[][7]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
     <data soapenc:arrayType="xsd:anyType[10]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:decimal">171930</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:decimal">2227</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:decimal">8930</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">Regional Literacy Training for K-3 Teachers (LETRS) - C2P2</data>
      <data xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2015-09-17T05:00:00.000Z</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">Thad Cochran Center - USM Campus</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">Hattiesburg</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">MS</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">MDE</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">SRESA</data>
     </data>
     <data soapenc:arrayType="xsd:anyType[10]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:decimal">154937</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:decimal">1830</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:decimal">6773</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">Regional Literacy Training for K-3 Teachers (LETRS) - C2P1</data>
      <data xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2015-06-18T05:00:00.000Z</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">Trent Lott Center - USM Campus</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">Hattiesburg</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">MS</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">MDE</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">SRESA</data>
     </data>
     <data soapenc:arrayType="xsd:anyType[10]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:decimal">164799</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:decimal">2054</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:decimal">7910</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">Programming for Children with Challenging Behaviors </data>
      <data xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2015-02-27T06:00:00.000Z</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">Table 100 Conference Center</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">Flowood</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">MS</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">MDE</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">SMEC</data>
     </data>
     <data soapenc:arrayType="xsd:anyType[10]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:decimal">164894</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:decimal">2050</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:decimal">7898</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">Students with Emotional Disabilities in the Classroom</data>
      <data xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2015-02-26T06:00:00.000Z</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">Table 100 Conference Center</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">Flowood</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">MS</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">MDE</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">SMEC</data>
     </data>
     <data soapenc:arrayType="xsd:anyType[10]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:decimal">161217</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:decimal">2148</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:decimal">8360</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">Mississippi College and Career Ready Standards for ELA (Grades 6-8)</data>
      <data xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2015-02-04T06:00:00.000Z</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">Trent Lott Center - USM Campus</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">Hattiesburg</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">MS</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">MDE</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">SRESA</data>
     </data>
     <data soapenc:arrayType="xsd:anyType[10]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:decimal">161215</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:decimal">2145</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:decimal">8351</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">Mississippi College and Career Ready Standards for Mathematics (Grades 6-8)</data>
      <data xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2015-02-02T06:00:00.000Z</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">Thad Cochran Center - USM Campus</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">Hattiesburg</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">MS</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">MDE</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">SRESA</data>
     </data>
     <data soapenc:arrayType="xsd:anyType[10]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:decimal">158540</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:decimal">2053</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:decimal">7908</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">Behavior Interventions that Work!</data>
      <data xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2015-01-26T06:00:00.000Z</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">Jackson State University</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">Jackson</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">MS</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">MDE</data>
      <data xsi:type="soapenc:string">SMEC</data>
     </data>
    </data>
   </getUserRegistrationsReturn>
  </getUserRegistrationsResponse>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to take the strings from each array and have them ready in a way to populate a UITableView with them. How would I apply these strings to a UITableView?

Comment: If you google for `NSXMLParser` tutorials and examples, you'll find plenty of examples of how to do it.

Comment: @Rob I've done that, but I haven't found anything that parses an xml like this. Most examples parse xml with specific tags, while this has a <data> tag for every element, and has a columnList at the top to define each element.

Comment: The process is the same, except you use the `attributeDict` provided in `didStartElement` instead of relying solely upon `elementName` alone.